# Sum the values based on specific value for a date range in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two (2) worksheets titled:

- [Spending Journal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7ygK.png)
- [Spending Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3tPq.png)

I am attempting to sum all the values in the `'Spending Journal'!E:E` spreadsheet that meet both the following rules:

- `'Spending Journal'!D:D` matches with `'Spending Analysis'!B4`
- `'Spending Journal'!A:A` is between a date range between `>='Spending Analysis'!C3` & `<'Spending Analysis'!D3`

All date cells dates have been formatted as YYYY-MM-DD

---

The formulas I have used with no luck are the following:

- `=SUMIFS('Spending Journal'!E:E,'Spending Journal'!A:A,"'>='Spending Analysis'!C3",'Spending Journal'!A:A,"<'Spending Analysis'!D3",'Spending Journal'!D:D,'Spending Analysis'!B4)`
- `=SUM(VLOOKUP(B22,'Spending Journal'!D:E,'Spending Journal'!E:E),FALSE)`
- `=SUMIF('Spending Journal'!A4:E10000,'Spending Analysis'!E3>'Spending Journal'!A4:E10000>'Spending Analysis'!D3,XLOOKUP('Spending Analysis'!B22,'Spending Journal'!D:D,'Spending Journal'!E:E,"Error",0))`

---

I have been trying to think on this for a couple days so any help would be amazing, even if it is pointing me in the correct direction.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Apart from the fact that your first formula is referencing `'Spending Analysis'!B4` as opposed to your stipulated `'Spending Analysis'!A4`, I see no reason why that formula should not give you the correct result. Though it might be worth checking that all dates being referenced are valid (i.e. numeric) Excel dates, and not text representations of dates.

Comment: Also, `'Spending Analysis'!C3"`, for example, contains "Jan-21", which I presume is actually the date 01/01/2021 formatted as "mmm-yy". Were you hoping rather that this would be interpreted by your `SUMIFS` formula as the *end* of that month, i.e. 31/01/2021?

Comment: Edited the post to fix the typo on you first comment. And all dates are being represented with YYYY-MM-DD and still nothing.

Comment: Suggest you debug by changing your `SUMIFS` to `COUNTIFS` and gradually increasing the arguments until it returns 0. So start with `=COUNTIFS('Spending Journal'!A:A,"'>='Spending Analysis'!C3")`. If that returns 0 then you know where the issue lies. If not, try `=COUNTIFS('Spending Journal'!A:A,"'>='Spending Analysis'!C3",'Spending Journal'!A:A,"<'Spending Analysis'!D3")`. If that doesn't return 0, try `=COUNTIFS('Spending Journal'!A:A,"'>='Spending Analysis'!C3",'Spending Journal'!A:A,"<'Spending Analysis'!D3",'Spending Journal'!D:D,'Spending Analysis'!B4)`.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging suggestions, it got me to a solution!!

It looks like the `Spending Journal' Worksheet's column A:A (Date) is formatted incorrectly, even though I formatted the cells as a date. When I click on a cell or add a new entry it recognizes it is a date. 

How I fixed the column is: Data > Text to columns > Finish and it then actually recognized them as dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Problem that I had's Solution:**

The `Spending Journal' Worksheet's column A:A (Date) was formatted incorrectly (even though the cells said they are formatted as a date, and I had set them to that several times to double check).

When I clicked on a cell to edit it's value or added a new entry it recognizes it then recognized as a formatted date.

How I fixed the column to recognize the cells to be formatted as dates:

- *Data* > *Text to columns* > *Finish*

---

The Answer to the specific question I posed.

The following formulas I tried and worked:

```
=SUMIFS('Spending Journal'!E:E,'Spending Journal'!A:A,"'>='Spending Analysis'!C3",'Spending Journal'!A:A,"<'Spending Analysis'!D3",'Spending Journal'!D:D,'Spending Analysis'!B4)

=SUMIFS('Spending Journal'!$E:$E,'Spending Journal'!$A:$A,"<="&EOMONTH('Spending Analysis'!C$3,0),'Spending Journal'!$A:$A,">="&'Spending Analysis'!C$3,'Spending Journal'!$D:$D,'Spending Analysis'!$B4)
```

Answer (score 0):

In spending analysis cell 'C4' paste this:

```vb
=SUMIFS('Spending Journal'!$E:$E,'Spending Journal'!$A:$A,"<="&EOMONTH('Spending Analysis'!C$3,0),'Spending Journal'!$A:$A,">="&'Spending Analysis'!C$3,'Spending Journal'!$D:$D,'Spending Analysis'!$B4)
```

and it should be able to copy and fill the rest of the spending analysis cells.

Comment: Unfortunately this formula didn't work and I am unsure why since it is similar to the first formula I tried too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a software developer working on a product that generates excel formulas.

According to my software, this might be appropriate:
`=SUMIFS('Spending Journal'!E:E, 'Spending Journal'!D:D, 'Spending Analysis'!B4, 'Spending Journal'!A:A, ">="&TEXT('Spending Analysis'!C3, "YYYY-MM-DD"), 'Spending Journal'!A:A, "<"&TEXT('Spending Analysis'!D3, "YYYY-MM-DD"))`

Let me know if this is at all accurate.